# Getting error with Dynamic Pivot near 'as'

Tags: sql-server, pivot, case

Hello i need help i don't know where the error is

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Pivot

```
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max),@columns2 nvarchar(max),
        @sql nvarchar(max)      
SELECT @columns = (
     SELECT DISTINCT ','+QUOTENAME(Pregunta)
    FROM Preguntas WHERE IdEncuesta=69
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
SELECT @sql = N'
SELECT  Respuesta,'+STUFF(@columns,1,1,'')+'
(Select t.Pregunta as Pregunta,
--Error
    CASE WHEN r.Respuesta IS NULL THEN ''-''  ELSE r.Respuesta END AS Respuesta,
    CASE WHEN op.IdOpcionPregunta IS NULL THEN ''-''  ELSE z.NombreNivel END AS Respuesta,
    CASE WHEN r.ValorRespMultiple IS NULL THEN  ''-''  ELSE m.NombreOpcion END AS Respuesta,
    CASE WHEN r.IdOpcionUnicaPregunta IS NULL THEN  ''-'' ELSE u.NombreOpcion END AS Respuesta
    FROM Preguntas t
    INNER JOIN Participante p ON p.IdEncuesta = t.IdEncuesta
    inner join Respuestas r on r.IdPregunta = t.IdPregunta
    left join OpcionPregunta op on op.IdOpcionPregunta= r.IdOpcionPregunta
    left join OpcionPregunta m on m.IdOpcionPregunta= r.ValorRespMultiple
    left join OpcionPregunta u on u.IdOpcionPregunta= r.IdOpcionUnicaPregunta
    Left join OpcionesEscala z on z.IdOpcionEscala = r.IdOpcionPregunta
    WHERE t.IdEncuesta=69 AND p.EstadoRespuesta =1) as t
    PIVOT (
        MAX(Respuesta) FOR Pregunta IN ('+STUFF(@columns,1,1,'')+')
    ) as pvt'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I see you are trying to do a dynamic pivot. The way to debug dynamic sql is to print/select the created statement BEFORE you ever try to execute it.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that your injected columns don't have a `FROM` or `,` after them.

Comment: @Larnu I suspect that is only part of the issue here. That subquery stuff looks highly suspect too.

Comment: I agree, @SeanLange . That's just one quick spot for some code that we can't use to replicate the problem (or run).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `FROM` alter column list(3rd line):

```
SELECT @sql = N'
SELECT  Respuesta,'+STUFF(@columns,1,1,'')+'
FROM (Select t.Pregunta as Pregunta,
--Error
    CASE WHEN r.Respuesta IS NULL THEN ''-''  ELSE r.Respuesta END AS Respuesta,
    CASE WHEN op.IdOpcionPregunta IS NULL THEN ''-''  ELSE z.NombreNivel END AS Respuesta,
    CASE WHEN r.ValorRespMultiple IS NULL THEN  ''-''  ELSE m.NombreOpcion END AS Respuesta,
    CASE WHEN r.IdOpcionUnicaPregunta IS NULL THEN  ''-'' ELSE u.NombreOpcion END AS Respuesta
    FROM Preguntas t
    INNER JOIN Participante p ON p.IdEncuesta = t.IdEncuesta
    inner join Respuestas r on r.IdPregunta = t.IdPregunta
    left join OpcionPregunta op on op.IdOpcionPregunta= r.IdOpcionPregunta
    left join OpcionPregunta m on m.IdOpcionPregunta= r.ValorRespMultiple
    left join OpcionPregunta u on u.IdOpcionPregunta= r.IdOpcionUnicaPregunta
    Left join OpcionesEscala z on z.IdOpcionEscala = r.IdOpcionPregunta
    WHERE t.IdEncuesta=69 AND p.EstadoRespuesta =1) as t
    PIVOT (
        MAX(Respuesta) FOR Pregunta IN ('+STUFF(@columns,1,1,'')+')
    ) as pvt'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```